# Sql:Sum of row values in columns

Tags: sql, data-analysis, presto

I have a table with three columns:

```
Guid | event | timestamp
1236| page-view | 1234
1236 | product-view | 1235
1236 | page-view | 1237
2025 | add-to-cart
2025 | purchase
```

I want to write a query not using case statement to show the events in columns with the sum of their occurrences. I don’t want to use case for this since the events keep increasing and there are around 200 of them now.

Output I am looking for is something like this:

```
GUid | page-view | product-view | add-to-cart | purchase 

1236 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 
2025 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1
```

Comment: why the case when clause fits perfectly for this purpose, but presto has a PIVOT function https://docs.treasuredata.com/display/public/PD/SQL+Tips+for+Hive+and+Presto#SQLTipsforHiveandPresto-PIVOT.2

Comment: There are 200+ events, so I am looking at 200+ case events, so trying to see if there is a better solution than that.

Comment: For that you need dynamic SQL with pivot and presto as search words you will find somerhing

Comment: Ok, thank you! Let me look around, thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `case when`.

```
select   Guid
        ,count(case event when 'page-view'    then 1 end) as 'page-view'
        ,count(case event when 'product-view' then 1 end) as 'product-view'
        ,count(case event when 'add-to-cart'  then 1 end) as 'add-to-cart'
        ,count(case event when 'purchase'     then 1 end) as 'purchase'
from     t
group by Guid
```

| Guid | page-view | product-view | add-to-cart | purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1236 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2025 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c3e5753677d312a2ecf89d796f33ead&hide=1)

Comment: Is `pivot` function available in Presto which the OP is tagged with?

Comment: You were right, my bad. Here's an updated solution.

Comment: I also would recommend using `count_if` as shorthand alternative to the `count - case` approach

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  a.Guid ,
    ifnull ((SELECT count (Guid ) from table_a where  event in('page-view') and Guid = a.Guid  GROUP by Guid  ),0) as [page-view]  ,
    ifnull((SELECT count (Guid ) from table_a where  event in('product-view') and Guid = a.Guid  GROUP by Guid  ),0) as [product-view]  ,
    ifnull((SELECT count (Guid ) from table_a where  event in('add-to-cart') and Guid = a.Guid  GROUP by Guid  ),0) as [add-to-cart]  ,         
    ifnull((SELECT count (Guid ) from table_a where  event in('purchase') and Guid = a.Guid  GROUP by Guid  ),0) as [purchase ]  
        FROM table_a a
        GROUP by Guid
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).